# How do get jquery fullcalendar to pass additional parameters to my json feed script

Tags: json, fullcalendar

My code is as follows

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    weekMode: 'liquid',
    events: themeforce.events,
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.find('span.fc-event-title').html(element.find('span.fc-event-title').text());           
    }
});
```

where `themeforce.events` is a variable containing an encoded url of the json feed a php file - all works well.

I tried replacing events: themeforce.events, with

```
events: {
    url: themeforce.events,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        custom_param1: 'something',
        custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
    },
```

However now the calendar fails to load.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

I wanted the start and end times for a post ajax request and it took me a bit of time to work it out.

This might help you:

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        start: start.format(),
        end: end.format(),
        custom_param1: 'value 1',
        custom_param2: 'value 2',
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    },
    success: function(doc) {
        var events = [];

        $.each(doc,function (index, e) {
            events.push(e);
        });

        callback(events);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use extraParams as explained in doc : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {

eventSources: [

// your event source
{
  url: '/myfeed.php',
  method: 'POST',
  extraParams: {
    custom_param1: 'something',
    custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
  },
  failure: function() {
    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
  },
  color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
  textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
}

// any other sources...

]

});
```

Also be sure your feed's url return raw json data array !

Answer (score 0):

Just put "data" instead of "extraParams" in "events"

```
  events: {
    url: 'service.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        custom_param1: 'something',
        custom_param2: 'somethingelse'
    },
    failure: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    },
  }
```